# How to add compiler commands explicitly with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile

I am trying to debug the linking of my C++ program in Ubuntu. I have a "Makefile", and if I run "make" on this, then the program compiles and links fine. However, I want to create a "CMakeLists.txt" file, and run "cmake", to get the equivalent result.

The problem is, the "CMakeLists.txt" file I have written is not working as expected. So, what I would like to do is to add parts of the "Makefile" that does work, to my "CMakeLists.txt" file, and slowly change the "CMakeLists.txt" file until it breaks.

So my questions is: In my "CMakeLists.txt" file, how can I explicitly add commands that are sent to the comiler?

For example, if my "Makefile" has the following:

```
g++ main.cpp -L/usr/lib/alpha -lbeta
```

How can I pass the same arguments to the compiler, via cmake?

Comment: Why use cmake if you have a good enough `Makefile` ?

Comment: Because I'm just trying to learn cmake and make, not create a real project...

Comment: Makefile and CMake has different concepts. I don't think your approach is a good way to learn CMake. It's like learning C by converting an assembly program to C to a series of inline asm calls then "slowly changing" groups asm calls to C statements. Instead, convert logical units of your makefile to CMake. For example: `add_executable(maintarget main.cpp)`, `target_link_libraries(maintarget /usr/lib/alpha/libbeta.so)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find_library`, `find_package`, `link_directories` and `target_link_libraries` commands.

If you want to add compiler flags explicitly: `target_compile_options`

[cmake-commands](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-commands.7.html)

Comment: Yes, but it is exactly those commands which do not seem to be working for me. They do not seem to be able to find the libraries which the makefile is able to find. Therefore, I want to pass the exact same commands that the make file is using, and work from there.

Comment: I think you can achieve this by setting the CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAG and CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS.